# Can reserved keyword be used as variable in Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I'm starting to learn Cypher. I've read the openCypher specification, and I've spun up few different graph databases that use Cypher. At the moment I'm running Memgraph inside Docker.

Here is my query that works just fine

```
MATCH (p:Park)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS parks
CALL tsp.solve(parks) YIELD sources, destinations
WITH RANGE(0, SIZE(sources)-1) AS rows, sources, destinations
UNWIND rows AS unwind
RETURN sources[unwind] AS source, destinations[unwind] AS destination
```

The part that works, but I think that it shouldn't work is `UNWIND rows AS unwind`.

Under openCypher specification reserved keywords can't be variable names, but that's possible inside Memgraph.

If names of cypher commands/clauses are reserved, I shouldn't be able to use them as variable names. Am I right?

Comment: Even if Memgraph happens to support it now, it may not always; your code would not be portable to other graph DBMS's; and you would confuse people. So, just don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. I've checked the Memgraph GitHub issues, and this one is [already reported](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/370).